# Execute Javascript code in the ajax url page and display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i want to execute some javascript code in the ajax sending url . For some reason it is not working .
 Please see the following

```
  <input type="button" value="12">
   <div class="result"></div>

 $(".button").on("click", function(){
        var source1=$(this).val();

  $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: "result.php",
          data: {
            source1: sel_value,
            }
            });

});
```

in result.php

```
<script>
 $(".result").html(<?php echo $_POST['source1'];?>*10);
  ... and other jquery functions ...
</script>
```

Here i will send some data to result.php . Based on this data i have to do some operation in result.php . How can i do this . Please help .

Comment: Can you give a code of button on which you need to click and javaScript function execute ??

Answer (score 0):

Just add whatever operation you want to do in `result.php`:

```
echo "Data sent was " . $_POST['source1'];
```

Comment: sorry i need to execute javascript code . i type alert for showing that even alert is not working .

Comment: Yes, But I need to see your button HTML code, so according to that execute javascript code

Comment: please check now

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372272/how-to-use-an-api-for-international-gold-rate

Answer (score 0):

Here ajax job is to return the rendered response of `result.php` and you are using alert which can't be accessible by ajax. So you need to use php `return`

```
return "Response is" . $_POST['source1'];
```

Or you can also return json response

```
$data = $_POST['source1'];
$JsonResponse = json_encode($data);

echo $JsonResponse;
```

For json response you need add following in ajax 
`dataType: "json",`

Answer (score 0):

Js code

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
 var source1=$(this).val();

      $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: "result.php",
              data: {source1: source1,},
               success:function(data)
              {
               alert(data);//your php response
               }
          });

    });
```

PHP code (result.php)

```
<?php
echo $_POST['source1'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try with Following :

```
    $("[type=button]").on("click", function(){
    var source1=$(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "result.php",
      data: {
        source1: sel_value,
        }
    });

});
```

I hope this helps you.
Thank you.